# Difficult to distinguish the pronunciation between "musste" and "müsste"

Tags: pronunciation, resource

It is quite difficult to distinguish the sound of the words *musste* from *müsste.* Are these sounds also difficult for germans to distinguish in speech? Are there tips or resources to better produce and understand these two words?

Comment: This automatically linked question has answers with interesting resources: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23870/3237

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Q: Are these sounds also difficult for Germans to distinguish in speech?**
**A:** Well, I'm not German, I'm Austrian. But (like almost all Austrians) I am a German native speaker, and so I think I also can answer this question: **No, not at all.**
When I, many years ago, for the very first time heard about English native speakers having troubles to distinguish between these sound, I simply couldn't understand what could be hard at this task. For me, this difference seamed as big as the difference between the sounds of any other pair of vowels (Wiege - Waage; Berg - Burg).

#### Why is hearing this difference easy for Germans and other German native speakers, but hard for Englishmen and other English native speakers?

These two sounds sound as different and distinct to us native German speakers as the two sounds for *s* and *th* sound different to native English speakers (mouse - mouth, sick - thick). But in German there is no th-sound and in English is no ü-sound. So we German native speakers did not learn to hear a th-sound when we learned speaking as little kids, and English speaking toddlers didn't learn to hear the ü-sound.

So, a typical German native speaker who starts learning English as an adult will have serious troubles to perceive any significant difference between the sounds *s* and *th,* and when you are not able to hear that difference it is almost impossible to pronounce words like *sing* and *thing* differently.

For the same reason, almost all native English speakers who begin learning German in adulthood have difficulty with sounds that are commonly used in German but do not exist in English. English has no ch-sound (*ich, ach*) and no ü-sound (*Tür, Stück*). But these sounds are similar to the sound of *k* (acht - Akt) and *u* (drücken - drucken), and this is why English native speakers interpret the German ch-sound as *k* when they hear it and they interpret an ü-sound as *u*.

#### What can you do?

Fist step: Listen very carefully. You really have to listen to German native speakers with heightened attention, paying close attention to when you hear a *u* and when you hear a *ü.* Your brain is not trained to distinguish between these two sounds. The only thing you can do is to train your brain by listening very carefully. You have to listen very often and long to German speech. Otherwise you brain has no chance to learn the difference. Watch German movies. Go to websites of German TV stations and listen to the news. There are many German podcasts, some of them especially for people who learn German as a foreign language.

Second step: Try to reproduce these sounds. Minimal pairs can help here.

**Minimal pairs u - ü:**

- Sie **fuhren** fort. - Sie **führen** einen Hund.
- Ich habe eine **Mutter.** - Eure **Mütter** werden euch abholen.
- Georg hat einen **Bruder.** - Sandra hat zwei **Brüder.**
- Ich lasse ein Buch **drucken.** - Sie müssen den roten Knopf **drücken.**
- Die Band geht auf **Tour.** - Die **Tür** klemmt.
- Du musst das Tonband weiter zurück **spulen.** - Du musst das Geschirr **spülen.**

Note, that *ü* is also very similar to *i* and some people confuse these two sounds.
**Minimal pairs i - ü:**

- Karl hatte **vier** Asse. - Beethoven komponierte ein Klavierstück **für** Elise.
- Auf meinem Honigbrot sitzt eine **Biene.** - Der Schauspieler betritt die **Bühne.**
- Auf meinem Honigbrot sitzt eine **Fliege.** - Gestern sind wegen eines Pilotenstreiks viele **Flüge** ausgefallen.
- Auf dem Boden steht eine große **Kiste.** - Neapel liegt direkt an der **Küste.**
- Darf ich mit Leonie und Mia **spielen?** - Du musst das Geschirr **spülen.**

---

This part is off-topic, but fits well:
German and English as West Germanic languages are closely related, so their sound systems are very similar. Learning other languages and their sounds can be much harder. For example Chinese (Mandarin but also Cantonese) has many different sh-sounds and vowels that are hard to interpret in our vowel system. And when they meet and form syllables, these syllables sound to us all like *shi* (at least in Mandarin). There is a famous Chinese poem with the title *"The Story of Shi who eats Lions".* It is [available at YouTube](https://youtu.be/1351rxGlEw4). The duration of this video is 2 minutes and 4 seconds, and you hear the same poem twice: Frist in Mandarin, then in Cantonese. In both pronunciations you see the Chinese text and it's English translation. Once you heard this poem, you will be very happy that you "only" have issues with *ü* and *u* in German words.

Comment: The lack of sounds in one language compared to another can often be heard in accents.  For example a German accent in English is characterized by substituting 'z' and 's' for voiced and unvoiced 'th'. Of course there are many other differences that are less easy to recognize, and I think it's possible, if you have a good ear, to tell an Austrian accent from a German accent. I once heard what German speakers consider an American accent, and apparently it's not so much the lack of umlauts that is most noticeable but the American 'r'; the German 'r' is very tricky for Americans.

Comment: *For example Chinese (Mandarin but also Cantonese) has many different sh-sounds and vowels that are hard to interpret in our vowel system. And when they meet and form syllables, these syllables sound to us all like* shi *(at least in Mandarin).* – These syllables all sound like *shi* because that's what they are; it's not the consonant or vowel that differs, but the tone.

Comment: @RDBury "The lack of sounds in one language compared to another can often be heard in accents. For example a German accent in English is characterized by substituting 'z' and 's' for voiced and unvoiced 'th'." The issue German native speakers have with 'th' is less about hearing than about speaking. I disagree that we have difficulties with hearing the difference between 'th'  and 's' . It's just that saying a 'th' requires a position of the tongue that is somewhat close to that of an 's' which leads to the substitution.

Comment: @Roland - I don't think that's what I said, or if I did that's not what I meant. I know what a German 'r' sounds like, but that doesn't mean I know how to say it. It's probably something similar with English 'th'. I think it's partly a matter a matter of of habit as well; I sure many native German speakers can say 'th' if they're thinking about it, but tend to revert to a 'z' sound in casual conversation.

Comment: @RDBury The question is about hearing differences between sounds. I understood your comment in that context.

Comment: @Roland - Okay. What I said was probably a drastic oversimplification anyway. I should try listening carefully to native German speakers listening to English to try to get the actual sound differences. Everyone has their own idiolect, even when speaking a foreign language, so Arnold Schwarzenegger speaking English does not sound like Christoph Waltz speaking English.

Comment: @rdbury this is difficult because voiced 'th' in onset is easily replaced by voiced /z/, which would suffice to contrast with German initial /s/. It is less straight forward with unvoiced 'th', but unvoiced initial /s/ would at least not clash with English initial /z/. More to the point, since *the* < \*so ~ \*to was a merger still ongoing in common Germanic, that's an interesting topic to consider. The question is if adjacent vowels had anything to do with it. (consider eg. *she* < Old E. *heo*)

Answer (score 4):

The opposition between the lax (short) vowels [ʊ], [ʏ] in *musste, müsste; [zucken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zucken), [zücken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/z%C3%BCcken)* is smaller and therefore harder to master for language learners than that between the tense (long) vowels [u], [y] in *[lugen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lugen), [lügen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%BCgen)*.

You should consequently start out by practicing the opposition between the tense vowels [i], [y] and [u]. This includes both listening to minimal pairs as *[liegen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/liegen), [lügen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%BCgen), [lugen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lugen)* and producing these sounds yourself. The key difficulty is learning to produce and perceive the front rounded vowel [y].

In order to learn to produce [y], start with [iiiiiyyyyyiiiiiyyyyy]: say [iiiii] and then round your lips as if blowing someone a kiss, producing [yyyyy], then unround them again. Take care not to alter the position of the tongue while doing this. After that, switch to words, but elongate the vowel: [liiiiigŋ̩], [lyyyyygŋ̩]. Gradually shorten the vowel until you arrive at [ligŋ̩], [lygŋ̩].

Having learned to produce [y], it should not be difficult to distinguish [u] from [y]. Producing [yyyyyuuuuuyyyyyuuuuu], you should notice that now it's the tongue that changes position, while the lip rounding remains constant. This is what makes the difference between [u] and [y] so prominent (for native speakers, at least): there is a huge articulatory difference in tongue positions (whereas [i] and [y] are actually much closer, the only difference being lip rounding).

Again, switch to words, starting with [lyyyyygŋ̩], [luuuugŋ̩] and gradually shorten the vowel until you arrive at [lygŋ̩], [lugŋ̩]. The opposition between the lax (short) vowels [ɪ], [ʏ], [ʊ], as in *[zicken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zicken), [zücken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/z%C3%BCcken), [zucken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zucken)* should then provide little additional challenge: they're just a little bit more open and central than their tense (long) counterparts.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a "minimal pair", and there are many more. I don't know how much value there is studying a single pair; I think it would be better to learn to distinguish between u and ü in general, not to mention the long and short versions of these vowels (for example Hütte vs. Hüte). Since the ü sound does not exist in English, it takes some practice for English speakers to hear the differences, and even more to reproduce the sounds accurately. For a single pair like this, try typing both words into Google Translate and clicking the speaker icon to hear them pronounced "side by side"; that should at least get you started hearing the difference.

Comment: Forvo is a great resource for soundbites in foreign languages. https://de.forvo.com/word/musste/ vs https://de.forvo.com/word/m%C3%BCsste/

Comment: u / ü have lip-rounding which i does not have. Adding that should help, but its difficult to motivate. Ignoring that, tense ü has the same tone as lax i, if I am not mistaken. So there can be no minimal contrast such as length or tone alone, except with English (compare how *Psycho* turned out differently; conversely, *pseudo*), which seems too berelevent in this answer not to mention.

Answer (score 3):

#### Are these sounds also difficult for germans to distinguish in speech?

No. The sounds of *musste* and *müsste* are clearly distinct for German speakers.

I assume you are an English native speaker (by your user name). Therefore, producing front rounded vowels like German Ü or Ö is not easy for you.

### Are there tips or resources to better produce and understand these two words?

Yes, there is a trick for better distinguishing between *musste* and *müsste*. With regards to pronunciation, Ü is not a variant of U, but of I. Pronounce *müsste* as if it were *misste* and you are almost there. Distinguishing between U and Ü is more important than distinguishing between Ü and I.

Historically, most German speakers pronounced Ü as I (and Ö as E). That pronunciation was normal in most central and southern German regions. The rounded front vowel pronunciation of Ü and Ö only became common with the raising prestige of the northern German pronunciation that went hand in hand with Prussia’s dominance in the late 19th century. In poetry, it is still acceptable to rhyme Ü with I (or Ö with E), e.g. in rhyme pairs such as *müsste–Kiste* or *Tür–ihr*, whereas U and Ü cannot rhyme.

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult for native speakers to distinguish ‘musste’ from ‘müsste’.